# I need to popup an image which is just selected, in Angular 7 and make it to popup when clicked

Tags: angular, image, popup, primeng

I used angular-modal-gallery to popup images which were already stored(fetching it from a REST API).
The problem is that the image which is just selected is not poping up.
*I am using PrimeNg*
This is my ts file function to store get image url and store it in image array of angular-modal-gallery.

```
     myUploader(event) {
    this.firstLoad = false;
    let fileData: File = null;
    fileData = <File>event.files[0];
    console.log(event.files[0]);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    this.imagePath = fileData;
    reader.onload = (event: any) => {
      this.imageURL = event.target.result;
      this.galleryImages.push( [] );
        console.log(this.imageURL);
        this.galleryImages[this.imageIndex].push(new Image (this.imageIndex,{
          img :this.imageURL
        }));
        console.log(this.galleryImages);
        this.imageIndex + 1;

    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileData); 


  }
```

This is how my html looks like:

```
                  <div
                      class="form-group"
                      [class.has-error]="productErrors.has('pictures')"
                    >
                      <div class="p-grid">
                        <label
                          for="productPictures"
                          class="p-col-2 control-label"
                          ><i
                            *ngIf="productErrors.has('pictures')"
                            class="fa fa-times-circle-o"
                          ></i>
                          Upload Pictures</label
                        >
                        <div class="p-col-10">
                          <p-fileUpload
                            name="product.productImages[]"
                            auto="true"
                            accept="image/*"
                            maxFileSize="1000000"
                            customUpload="true"
                            (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)"
                            multiple="multiple"
                          >
                            <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                              <div
                                *ngFor="
                                  let productImage of this.product.productImages
                                  let i = index
                                "
                              >
                                <div class="ui-fileupload-row">

                                  <div>

                                      <ks-modal-gallery [id]="0" [modalImages]="galleryImages[i]"></ks-modal-gallery>
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                    {{ productImage.standardImageName }}
                                  </div>
                                  <div>{{ productImage.size }} KB</div>
                                  <div>
                                    <button
                                      pButton
                                      type="button"
                                      icon="pi pi-times"
                                      (click)="remove(i)"
                                    ></button>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </ng-template>
                          </p-fileUpload>
                          <span
                            [hidden]="!productErrors.has('description')"
                            class="help-block"
                            >{{ productErrors.get("description") }}</span
                          >
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Click all tags ypu choose fpr ypur question amd remove the ones that are not applicable